# How to model collision between circle and the end of a line segment

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, collision-detection

I have a circle moving towards a fixed line segment (of finite length going from point A to point B). I want to simulate the collision (find direction and speed of circle after the collision) when the point of contact is the exact end of the line segment (say point B), not inside the line segment.

When the circle touches the line inside the segment, like a pool ball bouncing off a pool table rail, the equations are fairly easy or at leat easy to find. But what happens when the circle comes in contact with the line at the exact end of the segment? Is it like the collision of a circle and an infinitely smaller circle? What is the way to mathematically model that collision to determine where the circle is going after the collision?

I should mention that I'm looking for an answer to that question in the context of a game. So I'm more looking for something that will look realistic enough than for something that could be used in a real (i.e. super accurate) physics simulation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics and/or physics, not about programming.

Comment: Collisions are hard problems.  I doubt that you'll get a satisfactory answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direction or length of the line segment is not important, only the position of the end point where the circle hits.

I assume that:

- the line segment is fixed, i.e. it will not move.
- there is no energy going into rotation/spin of the circle
- it's an elastic collision; no friction; restitution is 100%

When the circle hits the endpoint, it will be as if it hit a line that is tangent to the circle at the point of impact. The velocity of the circle will be the original velocity mirrored in that tangent line. In other words, the velocity projected on the tangent line does not change. The velocity projected on the normal of the tangent line gets inverted.

[image]